# Outlook API - Getting Error BadRequest when using filter with OrderBy

Tags: outlook-api

I am building a test application to fetch mail and attachments.

If I use the request, which includes a filter of `IsRead=false` and `HasAttachments=true`, **it works**

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false%20AND%20HasAttachments%20eq%20true&$top=50`

If I use the request, whereby I have added an `OrderBy` and removed the second filter `HasAttachements`, **it works**.

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false&$orderby=Subject%20desc&$top=50`

If I use the request to include both filters and orderBy

`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false%20AND%20HasAttachments%20eq%20true&$orderby=Subject%20desc&$top=50`

**it breaks** with the following error 
`request.Result = {StatusCode: 400, ReasonPhrase: 'Bad Request', Version: 1.1`

can anyone see what I am doing wrong from the requests I am making?

Thanks in advance

---

From testing different scenarios the problem does seem to be with the filter `HasAttachments`

just `HasAttachments` filter **with** orderBy **breaks**
`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=HasAttachments%20eq%20true&$orderby=Subject%20desc&$top=50`

just `HasAttachments` filter **without** orderBy **works**
`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=HasAttachments%20eq%20true&$top=50` **works**

using 2 filters with orderBy (NOT `HasAttachments`) **works**
`https://outlook.office365.com/api/v1.0/me/messages/?$select=Sender,Subject&$filter=IsRead%20eq%20false%20AND%20Subject%20eq%20%27Test%27&$orderby=Subject%20desc&$top=50`

Answer (score 0):

By running the request in the browser I get a much more detailed error

`{"error":{"code":"InefficientFilter","message":"The restriction or sort order is too complex for this operation."}}`

So it appears that using a combination of some filters and sorting together are not allowed.

The way I would have to solve my problem is to include `HasAttachments` in my select clause and then filter the results returned.